# Как реализованы @staticmethod и @classmethod

Tags: python

Ребят, подскажите как реализованы эти декораторы.
Не смог найти реализацию в документации, может плохо искал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [документации есть пример реализации staticmethod и classmethod на чистом Питоне как не-дата дескрипторы](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods), вот [они отдельно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768768/4279).

Чтобы их понять, нужно знать что такое дескриптор в Питоне. Дескрипторы очень широко используются в языке, так что полезно разобраться.