# В чем отличие статического метода(@staticmethod) и метода класса (@classmethod). Python

Tags: python, ооп

Изучал PHP, немного имел дело с С++, начал учить питон и не могу понять одной вещи. Зачем нужен метод класса, если есть статический метод? В чем отличия между ними?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как реализованы @staticmethod и @classmethod](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/362466/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@staticmethod` определяет обычную функцию в пространстве имён класса. Может быть полезно для вспомогательных `_*` функций, чтобы не мусорить пространство имён модуля.

`@classmethod` создаёт метод класса. Объект класса явно передаётся через первый параметр как это с параметром `self` происходит для обычных методов. Также как и для `self`, переданный `cls` может отличаться от класса, в котором определён класс-метод (может быть потомок). Часто используется для создания альтернативных конструкторов ([`ArgumentParser.from_params()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656776/23044)):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys("abc")
OrderedDict([('a', None), ('b', None), ('c', None)])
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> DT.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 3, 18, 52, 8, 43534)
```

Исключение `__new__` метод, который является статическим (хотя `@staticmethod` не используется), а не класс-методом. [Why isn't `__new__` in Python new-style classes a class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9092072/4279). Есть [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), который является класс-методом, но не объявляется как таковой.

`@classmethod` участвуют в нескольких встроенных протоколах Питона, к примеру, `issubclass(klass, Divisible)` вызывает [`Divisible.__subclasshook__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23553777/4279).

Comment: классметод для альтернативных конструкторов? можете пример привести?

Comment: @Serhii: `datetime.fromtimestamp()`

Comment: @Serhii в ответе выше ещё примеры указаны: `OrderedDict.fromkeys`, `datetime.now`, `ArgumentParser.from_params`

Answer (score 2):

`@staticmethod`:

У метода этого типа нет неявной передачи `self` (объекта), ни неявной передачи `cls` (класса). Он как обычная функция - только с той разницей, что он вызывается из класса или из объекта.

`@classmethod`:

*Класс* объекта (`cls`) неявно передается как первый параметр, *нет* объект сам (`self`).