# Декораторы staticmethod и classmethod в Python

Tags: python

В чем отличие декораторов staticmethod и classmethod в Python. P.S. искал ответ, но пояснения максимально не понятны

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем отличие статического метода(@staticmethod) и метода класса (@classmethod). Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779684/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0staticmethod-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-classmethod)

Answer (score 0):

```
@staticmethod
```

означает, что при вызове метода экземпляра, в качестве аргумента не будет передан сам экземпляр. Это нужно когда нам не нужно работать с атрибутами экземпляра.

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.rad = radius

    def sum(self, a, b):
        return a + b
    # здесь не используются атрибуты экземпляра, можно смело ставить @staticmethod
    
    #@staticmethod
    #def sum(a, b):
    #    return a + b


    def zone(self):
        return math.pi * self.rad ** 2
    #здесь используются атрибуты экземпляра
```

метод с декоратором @classmethod принимает первым аргументом не экземпляр класса, а сам класс, например

```
class Ball:
    @classmethod
    def set_max_size_of_ball(cls, value):
        cls.max_size = value
```

мы вызываем метод не у экземпляра, а у класса

```
Ball.set_max_size_of_ball(6)
```